# Read in file - change contents - write out to same file

Tags: python

I have to read in a file, change a sections of the text here and there, and then write out to the same file.

Currently I do:

```
f = open(file)
file_str = f.read() # read it in as a string, Not line by line
f.close()
#
# do_actions_on_file_str
#
f = open(file, 'w') # to clear the file
f.write(file_str)
f.close()
```

But I would imagine that there is a more pythonic approach that yields the same result.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That looks straightforward, and clear already. Any suggestion depends on how big the files are. If not really huge that looks fine. If really large, you could process in chunks.

But you could use a context manager, to avoid the explicit closes.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    file_str = f.read()

# do stuff with file_str

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(file_str)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I would generally suggest reading in text mode and writing in binary though I do this sort of thing regularly (including just yesterday).

Comment: @dash Oh yea, I just threw that in. It doesn't really make any difference on my platform. ;-)

Comment: Fixed. Read and write in text mode.

Answer (score 5):

If you work line by line you can use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) with inplace mode

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(mifile, inplace=1):
    print process(line)
```

if you need to process all the text at once, then your code can be optimized a bit using `with` that takes care of closing the file:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    file_str = f.read()
#
do_actions_on_file_str
#
with open(myfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_str)
```

Comment: I actually do regex stuff, so on the whole file. I can see how my question doesn't reflect that tho, I'll update it