# Python text file reading

Tags: string, python-3.x, syntax

So, I have created some code which goes a little bit like this:

```
import os
while True:
    DIRFIND = input(">")
    DIRREAD = os.system("dir %s > tmp" % (DIRFIND))
    with open("tmp","r") as myfile:
        DIRREAD = myfile.read().replace("\n", "")
    print(DIRREAD)
```

However nothing is written in the tmp file that is created and I have a sneaking suspicion that this has something to do with the syntax of the %s / % part of the code resulting in an error. Any ideas??

Comment: You're opening a file for reading "r", reading lines from it, and then modifying those lines in your local code (not in the file itself).

Comment: Files are not modified magically by calling replace, you need to write the changes to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read in file - change contents - write out to same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194665/read-in-file-change-contents-write-out-to-same-file)

Comment: What is the best way you would recommend fixing this? How would I modify the file itself if the only file created is the output from the executed command in the terminal?

Comment: It is all in the linked dupe.

Comment: OK, so that tells me how to write in a file - what I'm asking is how to write something in the os.system("dir %s > tmp" % (DIRFIND)) where DIRFIND is something like C:\Users\, and therefor the command output to run from dir C:\Users\ ...