# python 3 : replace text in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file `city.py`，I want to do two things below：

1.copy `city.py` to be `newyork.py` and `losangeles.py`.

2.there is a word `city` in `city.py`,I want to replace it with `newyork`and `losangeles`.

I write a file `copy_city.py` to do this：

```
import shutil

def copy_city():
    cities = ['newyork', 'losangeles']
    for c in cities:
        city_file_name = c +'.py'
        shutil.copyfile('city.py',city_file_name)
        with open(city_file_name, "r+") as f:
            read_data = f.read()
            read_data.replace('city', c)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    copy_city()
```

**question：**
The file `city.py` can be copied successfully,but the word `city` in file `newyork.py` and `losangeles.py` can not be replaced.why is it?

Comment: `File "c.py", line 8, in copy_city with open(city_file, "r+") as f:
NameError: name 'city_file' is not defined`

Comment: `replace` does not modify the file in-place, it returns a new string with the replaces values

Comment: @surfer190 `city_file` should be `city_file_name`,I have update it.

Comment: @Wondercricket how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

I used this [answer about reading and writing contents to the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194665/read-in-file-change-contents-write-out-to-same-file)

```
import shutil

def copy_city():
    cities = ['newyork', 'losangeles']
    for c in cities:
        city_file_name = c +'.py'
        line = ''
        shutil.copyfile('city.py',city_file_name)
        with open(city_file_name, "r") as f:
            read_data = f.read()
            line = read_data.replace('city', c)
            f.close()

        with open(city_file_name, "w") as f:
          f.write(line)
          f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    copy_city()
```